# Single query to update records with different values based column value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update a column `person_id` in a table based on the other column `family_id`. Multiple records can contain for each family id. I want to set `person_id` values starting with 1 and increment by 1 for each family.

Is there any single query to do so? or I can have some loop for the families and set the values?
Using Oracle 10g and I need to provide this logic in a package.

Comment: Show us the tables definitions and what have you tried, please.

Comment: please provide the table details

Comment: table details? what table details you are expecting? A table with two integer fields namely 'family_id' and 'person_id'. And I need to reset person_id values based on family_id. Is this enough?

Comment: @hemanth: would be clearer with sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd5bea/5)**

**Below is the Update Query**

```
Update Temp
   set col1 = (select T3.myrank
                 from Temp T1,(select T2.id,rank() 
                                      over (partition by 
                                            T2.family_id
                                      order by T2.id) as myrank
                                 from Temp T2) T3
                where t1.id = T3.id
                  and t1.id = Temp.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I have it. Here is my simple example:

```
create table test_epn
(
  person_id number,
  family_id number
);

insert into test_epn values(10, 1);
insert into test_epn values(11, 1);
insert into test_epn values(12, 1);
insert into test_epn values(20, 2);
insert into test_epn values(21, 2);
```

The table is:

```
person_id   family_id
10          1
11          1
12          1
20          2
21          2
```

The function `row_number` will allow us to re-index, as the following statement shows:

```
select e.*, row_number() over
            (partition by e.family_id order by e.person_id) new_person_id
from test_epn e;

person_id   family_id   new_person_id
10          1          1
11          1          2
12          1          3
20          2          1
21          2          2
```

Now we "just" have to update the table thanks to this new column `new_person_id`:

```
update test_epn e
set e.person_id = (
  with w as
  (
    select f.person_id, f.family_id, row_number()
           over (partition by f.family_id order by f.person_id) new_person_id
    from test_epn f
  )
  select w.new_person_id
  from w
  where w.person_id = e.person_id
)
;
```

We then have what I think you want:

```
person_id   family_id
1          1
2          1
3          1
1          2
2          2
```

Comment: Solution needed in `oracle`. your post is good but its in `SQL Server`

Comment: I don't think so, since I tested my solution under Oracle 11g :-)